# html5 canvas context is blurry in fullpage

Tags: html, canvas

HTML5 canvas showing blurry context.

The red rectangle, on green background:

[image: the red rectangle, on green background]

When I made the canvas width & height == window width & height (fullpage). Also it is showing a horizontal scrollbar even if the `body{ margin: 0; }`. How can i fix this ?

my code

html ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <canvas></canvas>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css ->

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
}
canvas
{
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    background: green;
}
```

jquery ->

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.fn.showMSG = function(){

        var canvas = $("canvas");
        var ctx    = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

        canvas.width($(window).width());
        canvas.height($(window).height());

        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);

    }

    $(window).ready(function(){
        $.fn.showMSG();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is calling the `.width()` and `.height()` methods on the canvas. This doesn't change the `height` and `width` attribute of the canvas, but rather its `height` and `width` style which causes it to look stretched. Instead use `.attr()` to change the `height` and `width` attribute of the canvas.

See working example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.fn.showMSG = function() {

    var canvas = $("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

    canvas.attr('width', $(window).width());
    canvas.attr('height', $(window).height());

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

  }

  $(window).ready(function() {
    $.fn.showMSG();
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <canvas></canvas>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's working, but why there is a horizontal scrollbar ?

Comment: @MorshedSaif Please see my updated example (body css)